# How to make a coin spin with php

Tags: php, html

I need to select head if `mt_rand == 0`  and select tail if `mt_rand == 1` and show head or tail in coin coin.gif
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cu8zR.gif)

[demo](http://www.headortailbet.com)

sample code

```
function cointoss () {
$cointoss = mt_rand(0,1);
$headsimg = '<img src=""/>';
$tailsimg = '<img src=""/>';
if ($cointoss == 1){
    print $headsimg;
} else {
    print $tailsimg;
} 
return $cointoss;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: so whats the question?

Comment: you mean like animation?

Comment: You can't make a coin spin in php. You can show an image that spins on the page, but that is it. If you want to slow down that spin or stop it then you need a front end language

Answer (score 1):

You return wrong value, you have to return your image:

```
function cointoss () {

    $cointoss = mt_rand(0,1);
    $headsimg = '<img src=""/>';
    $tailsimg = '<img src=""/>';

    if ($cointoss == 1)
        return $headsimg;
    else
        return $tailsimg;
}
```

And for use:

```
<div class="img-container"><?php echo cointoss (); ?></div>
```